# Use a folder if it contains x or greater amount of files

Tags: python

Im trying to us os.walk to find all the files and folders in a directory.  Then I only want the folders with x amount of files in them.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=False):
    for d in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, d)) +  "    directories"
        for fi in files:
            if fi >= 4:
                print(os.path.join(root, fi)) + "   these are files"
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one crucial part in your code. You aren't taking the size of the files in each directory in your conditional.

You are doing this:

```
if fi >= 4:
```

When you want to do this:

```
if len(fi) >= 4:
```

Furthermore, you need to pay attention to what each iteration is giving you. Inside your loop, you proceed to iterate over all the files, when I think what you want to do simply check how many files are at each level. Look at my solution to understand what went wrong in your code.

I ran the code on my end and it worked. It should look like this:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    if len(files) >= 4:
        for f in files:
            print(os.path.join(root, f))
```

Answer (score 1):

`fi` would be the name of a given file in the current folder (as your `print` statement attests to); to see how many files are in that folder, check the size of `files`.